# How can I easily add the nonextensible attribute to IDL generated from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com-interop, idl

I'm exposing a C# class and interface for COM Interop for use in a legacy VB6 application. I noticed VB6 will not throw compile-time errors if a property is not properly exposed to COM through the C# interface. I've read that adding `nonextensible` to the IDL attributes would help with this and clue VB6 into the fact that missing properties should produce compile errors. However, I currently rely on Visual Studio to produce the TLB via the "Register for Com Interop" option.

Inspecting the generated TLB shows the interfaces like:

```
[
    odl,
    uuid(EB1E1F97-23B7-4487-9A3C-F5C6B7F9A8EC),
    version(1.0),
    dual,
    oleautomation,
    custom(0F45F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "IMyInterface")

]
interface IMyInterface: IDispatch {
...
}
```

My question is -- is there a way to get Visual Studio to easily produce a tlb that includes `nonextensible` in the IDL interface? It doesn't happen a lot but would on rare occasions help spot errors before they go into production so I'd like to know if there is any easy way to make this work without manually modifying IDL, recreating the TLB, and reembedding the tlb in the dll.

Comment: If's not marked as nonextensible, it's because it's extensible (duh...). If you want nonextensible, add `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` to your defining class, but this has implications (read the doc). In other words, all this is by design. Otherwise, if you go the hacking route, note you don't need to embed .TLB in .DLLs you can just build TLBs and reference them instead of .DLLs

Comment: But I'm already explicity defining an interface for my class that is dual... I was under the impression this would effectively result in the same IDL except I can define an explicit GUID for the interface.

Comment: I tried applying AutoDual and removing the explicit interface as you suggest and it had no effect. I believe all AutoDual does is ensure a dispinterface and interface are automatically generated.

Comment: AutoDual should generate quite a different tlb. You don't see any difference?

Comment: Doh, I see it now. I must have clicked the wrong version of my lib in OleView earlier. Very interesting... So is this because I don't have an explicit interface and therefore can't derive another interface from it? I kept reading it was better to have an explicit interface to keep GUIDs consistent and all, but I'm still learning. We aren't needing other apps to use these COM interfaces so it's pretty safe to change them any way we like from update to update.

Comment: A given COM interface layout (list of methods and their signature, names are irrelevant) is identified solely by its IID (guid). So, this layout is supposed to be carved in stone forever once you have "published" it and the IID. If you create COM interfaces from .NET, code the client and the server, and make sure deployment strictly follows changes, AutoDual is very easy to use. There are pros and cons to both approaches